# Button set to nil Swift 2

Tags: ios, button, null, swift2, xcode7

I am developing an app using Swift 2 and Xcode 7. I have done the following code countless times and I was successful:

```
 button.setTitle("New Title, forState: .Normal)
```

However, now I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error. When I tried `print(button)`, I got the error there. It says `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I am pretty sure that `button` is set to nil. I am connecting the button from the Main.Storyboard to the ViewContoller.swift What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

(1) The button outlet is not correctly connected in the storyboard.

(2) This ViewController instance is not the one in the storyboard.

(3) You're calling this code too soon (e.g. in `prepareForSegue`).

Comment: I have connected the button outlet the same way I have been doing while using Xcode 6. The view controller is the correct one. I am using this code in "ViewDidLoad".

Answer (score 0):

Outlets are usually declared as implicitly unwrapped optionals. (with an explanation point after the type.)

This means that it can be nil, but that you guarantee that before it's used, it will be set to a non-nil value.

You don't need to unwrap it, but referencing it if it IS nil will crash.

You should be able to use this form:

button?.setTitle("New Title, forState: .Normal)

That will skip the method call if button is nil.

(I say "should be able to" because I've been working with Objective-C for the past month and a half and my Swift is starting to get a little rusty.)

Comment: I want to run the code for sure. Why is the button set to nil in the first place? How do I not make it nil?